# Is it possible to update a Sybase datetime column that defaults to current time?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

A Sybase table with a column called "update_time" is a datetime type and defaults to the current time whenever the row is updated.  However, I want to update the "update_time" of a row to a time in the past, but it just keeps putting to the current time.  Is it possible to make this kind of change?

The query I'm using to try the update:

```
update table set update_time = '09-21-2015 12:00:00.000 PM' where id=1;
```

After I run this, the update_time for that row just goes to the current time when I run the query, not that actual time in the query.

Comment: Please add code examples of what you have tried.

Comment: You probably have an update trigger on that table. Disable it and then run your update

Comment: I agree with @Meet ,if you are using sybase-ase you probably have trigger on that table. IQ doesnt have triggers, but it can be something else.

Comment: I wouldn't have permission to change the trigger unfortunately, so I guess it's not possible.

Comment: What are you using: ASE or IQ?

Comment: @theweeknd Currently no access to IQ but there are triggers with IQ16 http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1601/doc/html/saiq-create-trigger-statement.html

Comment: @frlan oh...thats interessting, currently working with 15.4 ...we are going to v.16 next year...thx for the info, still it is true for the older versions :)

-at johng2: search for the trigger and if it exists, see what he does...i rly dont see any other explanation, the dbms doesnt have a mind of its own...it only does what you tell it to do ;)

Comment: @theweeknd But to be honest, I didn't try it by now and I expect it to be quiet slow (as every procedure on IQ)

Comment: You don't have to change the trigger, triggers can be disabled on a per-session basis, so there is a chance you may be able to do that.  `set triggers {on | off}`  - it does require *replication_role* though